# phpBB3 install new style

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I am trying to install a new style on my phpBB3 forum and it's not visible for installing on the ACP.

According to [this guide](https://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/how-to-install-styles-on-phpbb3/), it should be a simple drag n' drop into the FTP and then the style would be visible on the ACP for the actual installation. Yet, I still only see the already installed Styles (at ACP -> Styles -> Styles). Any ideas on why is this happening or where should I look to?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to unpack style from .zip archive, then you'll get folder with name similar to the style name with imageset, template, theme folders and file named style.cfg inside. You have to upload this folder into /styles of your forum on FTP server and install it at ACP -> Styles -> Styles

Comment: Ye I know that and as I have said above, I do not see it listed in "Styles". Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have original zip? Can you upload it somewhere and give me a link? Or where have you downloaded it?